# Find $[\sqrt{1}]+[\sqrt{2}]+[\sqrt{3}]+....+[\sqrt{2019}]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Let [$x$] denote the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$. Find the value of $$[\sqrt{1}]+[\sqrt{2}]+[\sqrt{3}]+....+[\sqrt{2019}]$$

I was able to find out the general pattern in the series i.e. $3(1)+ 5(2)+ 7(3)+\ldots+87(43)$ but was unable to proceed further.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You need a formula for $\sum\limits_{n=1}^N n(2n+1)$?  Do you know a formula for $\sum\limits_{n=1}^N n^2$ and for $\sum\limits_{n=1}^N n$?

Comment: I know people would downvote this (if they could) but I would just use excel. It's faster than any formulas, and you are more sure it's correct.

Comment: Just keep going then you have $44 + 44 + 44+ 44+.....$ for how many times.  ($44^2 = 1936$ so you you have $[\sqrt{1936}], [\sqrt{1937}],........ [\sqrt{2019}]$ all equal to $44$.  How many terms are there from $1936$ to $2019$ inclusive).

Comment: @PeterFranek Or Python. I use mpmath and other libraries as a Swiss Army Knife for problems.

Comment: @PeterFranek Yeah, but that's not doing mathematics.  That's just doing bookkeeping..

Comment: The usual notation for the “greatest...” is $\left\lfloor\cdots\right\rfloor$ which is given by $\verb* \left\lfloor\cdots\right\rfloor*$.

Comment: @PeterFranek That's the first thing I thought of, but I wanted to know the mathematical way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint 1:   $[\sqrt{n^2}], [\sqrt{n^2 +1}], .........[\sqrt{(n+1)^2 - 1}]$ all equal the same the same thing: $n$.

Hint 2: $(n+1)^2 - 1= n^2 + 2n$ so from $[\sqrt{n^2}]$ to $[\sqrt{(n+1)^2 - 1}]=[\sqrt{n^2 + 2n}]$ there are $2n+1$ terms.

Hint 3: So  we have $\color{blue}{[\sqrt {1}] + [\sqrt 2]+ [\sqrt 3]} + \color{purple}{[\sqrt 4] + ....+[\sqrt 8]} +\color{orange}{[\sqrt 9]+ ....+[\sqrt{15}]}.....+\color{green}{[\sqrt M^2]+...... + [\sqrt {(M+1)^2-1}]} + \color{red}{[\sqrt {(M+1)^2}] + ...... + \sqrt{2019}}$  where $(M+1)^2 \le 2019 < (M+2)^2$.

============

Solution:

$M+1= 44$ and $44^2 = 1936$ so so we have

$\color{blue}{1 + 1+ 1} + \color{purple}{2 + ....+2} +\color{orange}{3+ ....+3}.....+\color{green}{43+...... + 43} + \color{red}{44 + ...... + 44}$

$\color{blue}{1\cdot (2\cdot 1 + 1)} + \color{purple}{2\cdot (2\cdot 2 + 1)} +\color{orange}{3\cdot (2\cdot 3 + 1)}.....+\color{green}{43\cdot (2\cdot 43 + 1)} + \color{red}{44\times(2019-1936+1)}=$

$\sum_{k=1}^{43}[k(2k+1)] + 44\cdot 84=$

$2\sum_{k=1}^{43} k^2+\sum_{k=1}^{43} k + 3696$

..... and that's it.  Apply $\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac {n(n+1)}2$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac {n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$ and you are done.

Comment: Thanks mate!!!!

Comment: You absolutely nailed the question.